# BUCLE para obtención automática de texto de un archivo .txt para posterior uso con pyautogui

Tags: python, archivo, bucles, txt

necesito algo de ayuda, estoy haciendo un script sencillo en **python**, que lee las líneas de un archivo de texto **.txt** y obtiene las preguntas y sus respuestas, que mas tarde incorporaría a un código mas extenso para su uso con **pyautogui** para crear un cuestionario de evaluación de forma automática. El problema que tengo es que no consigo hacer que funcione bien el **bucle** para que vaya incorporando las preguntas y su correspondientes respuestas en el orden correcto.

Lo siguiente es un sencillo ejemplo, pero en la realidad el archivo **.txt** tendría bastantes más preguntas por lo cual necesitaría que se fuera incrementando automáticamente el número de linea que va leyendo para así poder leer todas las preguntas y sus respuestas. Es decir, que empezara por la pregunta 1ª y se ejecutara en bucle hasta llegar a la última pregunta del archivo **.txt**.

> Código

```
def Pregunta():
    contador = 0
    while contador < 8:
        with open ("lista.txt", "r") as f:
            line1 = f.read()      
            line1 = (line1.split('\n')[contador])
            print (line1)                   
            contador = contador +6


def Opción1():
    
    contador1 = 1
    while contador1 < 9:
        with open ("lista.txt", "r") as f:
            line1 = f.read()      
            line1 = (line1.split('\n')[contador1])
            print (line1)
            contador1 = contador1 +6 

def Opción2():
    
    contador2 = 2
    while contador2 < 9:
        with open ("lista.txt", "r") as f:
            line1 = f.read()      
            line1 = (line1.split('\n')[contador2])
            print (line1)
            contador2 = contador2 +6 

def Opción3():
    
    contador3 = 3
    while contador3 < 10:
        with open ("lista.txt", "r") as f:
            line1 = f.read()      
            line1 = (line1.split('\n')[contador3])
            print (line1)
            contador3 = contador3 +6

def Opción4():
    
    contador4 = 4
    while contador4 < 11:
        with open ("lista.txt", "r") as f:
            line1 = f.read()      
            line1 = (line1.split('\n')[contador4])
            print (line1)
            contador4 = contador4 +6 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pregunta()
    Opción1()
    Opción2()
    Opción3()
    Opción4()
```

> Contenido archivo .txt

```
Lista de la compra
a) sal
b) azucar
c) leches
d) harina

Tipos de animales
a) perro
b) gato
c) leon
d) aguila
```

> Salida que obtengo:

```
Lista de la compra
Tipos de animales
a) sal
a) perro
b) azucar
b) gato
c) leches
c) leon
d) harina
d) aguila
```

> Salida que quiero obtener:

```
Lista de la compra
a) sal
b) azucar
c) leches
d) harina
Tipos de animales
a) perro
b) gato
c) leon
d) aguila
```

Comment: La verdad que no entiendo tu código, cada funcion es exactamente igual. Y para obtener el resultado que quieres basta con hacer `f.read()` y si lo quieres en forma de lista `lista = f.readlines()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer grave error es leer el mismo archivo cinco veces. Cuando procesas un archivo debes hacerlo en una sola pasada.

Segundo grave error es leer todo el archivo a memoria y luego partirlo en línea

```
    with open ("lista.txt", "r") as f:
        line1 = f.read()      
        line1 = (line1.split('\n')[contador1])
```

Es atrozmente ineficiente, consumidor de memoria y lento. Los archivos se procesan línea por línea.

#### Solución

Para esta solución ocupamos dos variables: `pregunta` es una lista de líneas de texto conteniendo la pregunta, y `alternativas` es un diccionario cuya clave es la letra y cuyo valor es el texto de la respuesta.

```
pregunta = []
alternativas = {}
```

Este proceso lee el archivo línea por línea,

```
for linea in f:
    #   Procesar el archivo una línea a la vez.

    linea = linea.rstrip()
```

y según donde está parado, va poniendo esa línea en `pregunta` o `alternativas`, según corresponda.

```
        comienzo = linea[:2]
        if comienzo[0] in 'abcd' and comienzo[1] == ')':
            alternativas[comienzo[0]] = linea
        else:
            pregunta.append(linea)
```

Cuando detecta que se acabo la pregunta (línea en blanco), la imprime, reinicializa las variables y sigue procesando el resto del archivo.

#### Demo

```
def imprimir(pregunta, alternativas):
    for p in pregunta:
        print(p)
    for alt in "abcd":
        print(alternativas[alt])
    print()
    
with open("lista.txt", "r") as f:
    #   Inicializamos para la siguiente pregunta
    pregunta = []
    alternativas = {}

    for linea in f:
        #   Procesar el archivo una línea a la vez.

        linea = linea.rstrip()

        if len(linea) > 1:
            #   Una linea no vacia.
            #   Si comienza con a), b), c) o d), es una respuesta.
            #   En otro caso, es parte de la pregunta.
            comienzo = linea[:2]
            if comienzo[0] in 'abcd' and comienzo[1] == ')':
                alternativas[comienzo[0]] = linea
            else:
                pregunta.append(linea)
        else:
            #   La pregunta y alternativas se acaban al encontrar una
            #   línea vacia de separación.

            imprimir(pregunta, alternativas)

            #   Inicializar las variables para la próxima pregunta.
            pregunta = []
            alternativas = {}

    #   Imprimir la última pregunta todavía pendiente
    imprimir(pregunta, alternativas)
```

produce:

```
Lista de la compra
a) sal
b) azucar
c) leches
d) harina

Tipos de animales
a) perro
b) gato
c) leon
d) aguila


Process finished with exit code 0
```